# Coinbase Wallet API - Set fee on send transaction

Tags: coinbase-api

Is it possible to set a fee (miner fee) on a transaction when sending BTC / ETH / LTC using the Coinbase Wallet API?

What I know:

1. Coinbase automatically sets the fee when using the website and this can't be customised.
2. The API documentation shows a parameter where one should be able to specify the fee (https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#send-money). However, making any requests with this parameter returns an error message:

   {"errors":[{"id":"validation_error","message":"The transaction fee has expired."}]}

Just want to know if it is possible to specify a fee at all, and if so how you went about it.

Comment: I am facing this problem too. Tried almost everything and nothing helps.

Hope someone known what is this.